# how to place a linked list node from a list of linked lists onto a heap in python

Tags: python, linked-list, heap

I think the title is more confusing than the actual problem description. So here it is

I have a `python` list of linked lists, which looks somethin like `lists = [[1,4,5],[1,3,4],[2,6]]`, and a linked list node is defined as

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
```

In the problem I'm trying to solve, the first step is to put a first element of each list onto a heap. Here is my code for it:

```
mylist1 = ListNode(1, ListNode(4, ListNode(5)))
mylist2 = ListNode(1, ListNode(3, ListNode(4)))
lists = [mylist1, mylist2]

import heapq
heap = []
for l in lists:
    heapq.heappush(heap, (l.val, l))
```

When I run this code I'm getting a following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 2, in <module>
    heapq.heappush(heap, (l.val, l))
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'ListNode' and 'ListNode'
```

I think I understand what is going on there, `python` treats `l` not as a single node, but as a whole list. So my question is, how do I put a first node from each list onto a heap in `python`? I feel like the answer is quite simple, but I'm missing something important.

**EDIT**

I'm trying to solve this problem, https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/. The approach is to use a heap, but I don't want to insert all the elements into it, what I want to do is to insert the first elements of each list, find the minimum element, then insert next element from the list which has the minimum and so on until I go through all the elements.

Comment: `heapq` implements a min heap, which does some comparisons between elements in the heap when you insert. You inserted 2 tuples of (int, ListNode) and since there was a tie in the int value for the first item in the tuple, it moves on to the second item in the comparison. ListNodes don't implement comparison, which caused the error. I don't think it has anything to do with treating `l` as a list.

Comment: Please explain which higher level problem you trying to solve? What is the bigger picture here?

Comment: @trincot I added an edit at the end of the question.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with putting `(l.val, l)` on the heap is that when two tuples have the same value in the first member (`val`), that then a comparison will happen between the second member values, i.e. between lists. But this operation is not defined. You can avoid this, by putting a third, unique value in those tuples, between the two members you already have. So you could define your heap like this:

```
for i, l in enumerate(lists):
    heapq.heappush(heap, (l.val, i, l))
```

As lists can be empty, you should add a condition:

```
for i, l in enumerate(lists):
    if l:
        heapq.heappush(heap, (l.val, i, l))
```

This is also the moment to tell you that it is more efficient to first collect those tuples in a standard list, and then call `heapify` on it:

```
heap = [(l.val, i, l) for i, l in enumerate(lists) if l]
heapq.heapify(heap);
```

Not your question, but if you cannot make the complete logic to work, here is a spoiler for the *rest* of the code:

> `tail = dummy = ListNode()
> while heap:
>     _, i, tail.next = heap[0]
>     tail = tail.next
>     if tail.next:
>         heapq.heapreplace(heap, (tail.next.val, i, tail.next))
>     else:
>         heapq.heappop(heap)
> return dummy.next`

Comment: The code with `for i, l in enumerate(lists)` didn't work. I'm getting an error stating, `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'ListNode'`. However the code with `heap.heapify(heap)` worked. Would you mind explaining what is happening? I'm not quite clear why it is working. What am I missing?

Comment: It means that not all tuples in the heap have those 3 elements. Make sure you consistently use the 3-member tuples, with the middle element being the unique `i` number.

Comment: See it run on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma701618125459839).

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this? =>

```
class ListNode:
def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
    self.val = val
    self.next = next
def __lt__(self,other):
    return self.val < other.val
def __le__(self,other):
    return self.val <= other.val


mylist1 = ListNode(1, ListNode(4, ListNode(5)))
mylist2 = ListNode(1, ListNode(3, ListNode(4)))
nodes = [mylist1,mylist2]

import heapq
heap = []
for l in nodes:
    heapq.heappush(heap, (l.val,l))
print(heap)
```

also take a look at this => [heapq push TypeError: '<' not supported between instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53554199/heapq-push-typeerror-not-supported-between-instances/53554555)

Comment: No, that's not what I'm looking for. All I want is to put the first element of each list onto a heap not the other elements.

Comment: how about this? I've edited my answer